# Пропуск слова. Знак препинания

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Какой знак препинания нужен в предложениях:

1) Он перенёс девушку с переднего сиденья на заднее и хорошенько укрыл.

2) Они избавились от старой одежды и надели новую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Он перенёс девушку с переднего сиденья на заднее (**сидение**) и хорошенько укрыл. 
Они избавились от старой одежды и надели новую (**одежду**).*

Это **неполные предложения,** пропущенные слова восстанавливаются по смыслу, никаких знаков при этом не требуется.

В неполных предложениях может ставиться **тире** в тех случаях, когда на месте пропущенного слова делается **пауза**. Обычно это касается пропущенного сказуемого, предложений с параллельной структурой и др. Все эти случаи рассматриваются у Розенталя.

Например: Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно плохо (Т.) Они смотрели друг на друга: Райский — с холодным любопытством, она — с дерзким торжеством (Гонч.);

При отсутствии **паузы** в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится: Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие (Леон.).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

Comment: Не решаюсь править, но — нАдели.

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже заметила ошибку, но исправить забыла при копировании. Такую правку, я думаю, можно делать и без разрешения автора.

Comment: Хорошо, буду иметь в виду.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon, за столь ясное объяснение.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма Михайловна, за правку

Answer (score 1):

В данных случаях обособление не требуется, если рассуждать нормативно. Единственным исключением может стать тире, создающее эффект неожиданности, однако для данного случая это как-то неуместно. Можно также посчитать, что данное действие имеет добавочный оттенок, близкий к обособленным членам предложения.

UPD1: перечитал заголовок и понял свою неточность. Если вы имели в виду слова: "сиденье" и "одежда", —  то они действительно пропущены для избежания тавтологии. Их роль выполняют субстантивированные прилагательные: "заднее" (сиденье) и "новая" (одежда).

UPD2: Да, и забыл сказать (спасибо Sharon), что такие предложения называют неполными(пропущено главное слово, в результате чего зависимое занимает его место и, соответственно, роль в предложении)

Comment: Спасибо большое, Бот Ботович